# An expression of type 'void' cannot be tested for truthiness

Tags: typescript

I don't want to push null, so I'm putting a condition to check, but there's a syntax error that says:

> "An expression of type 'void' cannot be tested for truthiness"

How do I do this correctly?

```
localStorage.setItem('todoitems', JSON.stringify(this.todoitems)) 
  ? localStorage.setItem('todoitems', JSON.stringify(this.todoitems)) 
  : [];
```

Comment: first get - then set

Comment: tried it but i think my code was wrong with the setitem, i tried the IF method its working, can you please post your solution too? as i am a beginner, i get the following error with setitem Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)
lib.dom.d.ts(15140, 26): An argument for 'value' was not provided. @MartinChaov

Comment: I just saw you are using typescript :) next time post the error you are getting. The answer given by adiga is correct.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since [`setItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) doesn't return anything, it is complaining about using a `void` type in a ternary operator where a boolean is expected

You can add an `if` condition on `this.todoitems` before `setItem`

```
if (this.todoitems !== null)
    localStorage.setItem('todoitems', JSON.stringify(this.todoitems))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be useful for someone...

In the simplest class of some service, the code for your task could look like this:

```
export class SomeService {

  constructor (public todoItems: object = { /* ... */ }) {}

  getItems (): string | null {
    return localStorage.getItem('todoItems')
  }

  setItems (): void {
    localStorage.setItem('todoItems', JSON.stringify(this.todoItems))
  }

  removeItems (): void {
    localStorage.removeItem('todoItems')
  }

  protected existItems (): boolean {
    return !!localStorage.getItem('todoItems')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below

```js
if (this.todoitems)
    localStorage.setItem('todoitems', JSON.stringify(this.todoitems))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).