# Issue with angular 4 ng-bootstrap module

Tags: angular

While creating angular 4 build. I got the following error. Can anyone help me out resolving this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUI87.png)? I am currently using `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-beta.5`

Comment: Check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57324502/an-expression-of-type-void-cannot-be-tested-for-truthiness

Comment: Working fine in case of dev build. The issue only comes during prod build.

Comment: can you provide some detail information about the "following error"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ng-bootstrap and Angular 9 compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62625522/ng-bootstrap-and-angular-9-compatibility)