# Ng-bootstrap and Angular 9 compatibility

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

After upgrading to Angular 9, I am getting the following errors relative to ng-bootstrap:

ERROR in src/app/shared/Components/form-controls/dropdown-select/dropdown-select.component.ts:87:63 -
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NgbDropdownMenu'.

87   @ViewChild('dropdownMenu', { static: false }) dropDownMenu: NgbDropdownMenu;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/private/private-shared/Services/ngb-modal-stack-extend.service.ts:1:39 - error TS2305: Module     '"../../../../../../../../../../../node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap"' has no exported member 'isString'. 1 import { NgbModalRef, NgbActiveModal, isString, isDefined, NgbModalBackdrop, ContentRef, NgbModal,
NgbModalWindow } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
~~~~~~~~
src/app/private/private-shared/Services/ngb-modal-stack-extend.service.ts:1:49 - error TS2305: Module
'"../../../../../../../../../../../node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap"' has no
exported member 'isDefined'.
1 import { NgbModalRef, NgbActiveModal, isString, isDefined, NgbModalBackdrop, ContentRef, NgbModal,
NgbModalWindow } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
~~~~~~~~~
src/app/private/private-shared/Services/ngb-modal-stack-extend.service.ts:1:60 - error TS2305: Module '"../../../../../../../../../../../node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap"' has no
exported member 'NgbModalBackdrop'.

1 import { NgbModalRef, NgbActiveModal, isString, isDefined, NgbModalBackdrop, ContentRef, NgbModal,
NgbModalWindow } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/private/private-shared/Services/ngb-modal-stack-extend.service.ts:1:78 - error TS2305: Module
'"../../../../../../../../../../../node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap"' has no
exported member 'ContentRef'.
1 import { NgbModalRef, NgbActiveModal, isString, isDefined, NgbModalBackdrop, ContentRef, NgbModal,
NgbModalWindow } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/private/private-shared/Services/ngb-modal-stack-extend.service.ts:1:100 - error TS2305:
Module '"../../../../../../../../../../../node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap"' has
no exported member 'NgbModalWindow'.

1 import { NgbModalRef, NgbActiveModal, isString, isDefined, NgbModalBackdrop, ContentRef, NgbModal,
NgbModalWindow } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

```
Package.json 

    "@angular/cdk": "9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "9.1.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "9.1.11",
    "@angular/core": "9.1.11",
    "@angular/forms": "9.1.11",
    "@angular/localize": "9.1.11",
    "@angular/material": "9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "9.1.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "9.1.11",
    "@angular/router": "9.1.11",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "4.1.2",
    "rxjs": "6.3.3",
    },
    "devDependencies": {
       "@angular-builders/jest": "^7.2.0",
      "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.0",
      "@angular/cli": "^9.1.9",
      "@angular/compiler-cli": "9.1.11",
      "@schematics/angular": "^9.1.5",
```

Comment: Is Ngbdropdownmenu imported?

Comment: I have added import { NgbDropdownMenu } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'  and i m getting an error 
Property '_menu' is private and only accessible within class 'NgbDropdown' for this code:                                        @ViewChild('dropdownMenu', { static: false }) dropDownMenu: NgbDropdownMenu;

  @HostListener('window:resize')
  onResize() {
    if (
      this.dropDownMenu.isOpen &&
      this.dropDownMenu.dropdown._menu.placement === 'top'

Answer (score 3):

update your version related to below table

```
  ng-bootstrap    Angular Bootstrap CSS
    1.x.x           5.0.2   4.0.0
    2.x.x           6.0.0   4.0.0
    3.x.x           6.1.0   4.0.0
    4.x.x           7.0.0   4.0.0
    5.x.x           8.0.0   4.3.1
    6.x.x           9.0.0   4.4.1
    7.x.x          10.0.0   4.5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

ng-bootstrap 4.x.x is meant for Angular 7. You need to update it to ng-bootstrap 6.x.x in order for it to work with Angular 9. [Here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started) you may check ng-bootsrap compatibility table as well as installation instructions